# Does anyone have any really good quantum computing illustration packages or frameworks for visually teaching various aspects of QC?

Tags: programming, resource-request

I'm focusing on training non quantum physics / non math majors - software engineers to be specific (and the interested senior executive that wonders by) and am bewildered by the lack of adequate training vehicles for non-quantum indigenous folks.

I'm searching for good quantum computing illustration packages or frameworks for visually teaching various aspects of QC that are interactive in nature?

For instance QUIRK does a very good job, as does the OReilly JS QC simulator - both useful to teaching purposes but we need more to really bring QC to software engineers.

Some other examples are the Bloch Sphere Playground and the Quantum State Sphere Playground. (links below)

My preference is for interactive vehicles like "Immersive Math" when it comes to explaining linear algebra concepts visually and interactively.

There has to be some decent vehicles out there that provide more coverage on under served fronts of QC, but I just can't seem to find them.

**Links**:

**QUIRK**: - https://algassert.com/quirk

**OReilly QC**: - https://oreilly-qc.github.io/#

**Immersive Math**: - http://immersivemath.com/ila/index.html

**Bloch Sphere Playground**: https://javafxpert.github.io/grok-bloch/

**Quantum State Sphere Playground**: https://javafxpert.github.io/quantum-state-spheres/

Comment: There are some good resources on [QuVis](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/physics/quvis/)

Comment: @ProfVersaggi, I would say notebooks with interactice plots would work well, especially if you have software engineers, they would love to see code. Here is a repo with many of those : https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials